# Any material-ui simple/basic themes collection similar to bootswatch?

Tags: material-ui

I've been looking for simple themes similar to https://bootswatch.com/ for material-ui.

By "simple" I mean just the JSON/POJO that needs to be fed in `createMuiTheme`. It can contain any `overrides` of Global styles but preferably no component wrappers or other react jsx/tsx code.

Am I missing any technical reason why such a basic theme collection does not exists ? Are global styles considered bad practice with material-ui ?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://material-ui.com/store

Comment: @NearHuscarl tnks for the reply, if you look on some of the free themes' code you will see that most custom styling is inside react components. I was looking for a theme (JSON/POJO format) in which all styling was changed globally, e.g. besides color palette also fonts/sizing/spacing/radius/borders/gradients/etc ... change the look of material-ui with one global theme object

Comment: So I take it nothing like this exists?

Comment: @MattWest I did not find anything ...